# Line representation using dot product and cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

From the [2.4.1](https://vlecomte.github.io/cp-geo.pdf#subsection.2.4.1) section of the attached book:

> Equation $ax+by=c$ can be interpreted geometrically through dot product: if we consider $(a,b)$ as a vector, then the equation becomes $(a,b)·(x,y) =c$.  This vector is perpendicular to the line, which makes sense:  we saw in 2.3.1 that the dot product remains constant when the second vector moves perpendicular to the first.
>
> The way we’ll represent lines in code is based on another interpretation. Let’s take vector $(b,−a)$, which is parallel to the line. Then the equation becomes a cross product $(b,−a)×(x,y) =c$. Indeed, we saw in 2.3.2 that the cross product remains constant when the second vector moves parallel to the first.
>
> In this way, finding the equation of a line going through two points $P$ and $Q$ is easy: define the direction vector $\vec{v} = (b,−a) = \vec{PQ}$, then find $\vec{v}×P$.

I know that $ax+by$ equivalent to $(a,b)·(x,y)$ using dot product, but I can't understand what does the author mean in the following sentence "the dot/cross product remains constant when the second vector **moves perpendicular/parallel** to the first".

Also, moving to the equation $\vec{v} = (b,−a) = \vec{PQ}$ is still ambiguous for me.

kindly, write down omitted steps and some helpful drawing if it's possible.

Comment: The idea is this: if $v \perp w$ then $v \cdot w = 0$, so if $(c,d)\perp (a,b)$ then $(a,b) \cdot [(x,y)+(c,d)] = (a,b) \cdot (x,y) + (a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (a,b) \cdot (x,y)$

Comment: The _cross_ product doesn’t remain constant when the second vector moves perpendicular to the first. Indeed, as is stated in the quoted block, is remains constant when the movement is _parallel_, not _perpendicular_.

Comment: Sorry, but as a non-native speaker of English, I can't understand (or I'm not sure) how does a vector move perpendicular or parallel to another one.

Comment: See @dcolazin’s comment.

Comment: @dcolazin If I'm not wrong, you mean that for any two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, if we add a vector $\vec{w}$ to $\vec{v}$ where $\vec{w} \perp \vec{u}$, then $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=\vec{u}\cdot(\vec{v}+\vec{w})$, and this operation means that vector $\vec{v}$ moves perpendicular to vector $\vec{u}$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @dcolazin and @amd for their helpful comments.

---

Given two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ in Cartesian coordinates:

> The dot product $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$ remains constant when $\vec{v}$
>   moves perpendicular to $\vec{u}$.

That is because if we add a vector $\vec{w}$ to $\vec{v}$, where $\vec{w} \perp \vec{u}$:

Then $\vec{u}\cdot(\vec{v}+\vec{w})=\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}+\vec{u}\cdot\vec{w}=\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}+0=\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$.

> The cross product $\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$ remains constant when
>   $\vec{v}$ moves parallel to $\vec{u}$.

That is because if we add a vector $\vec{w}$ to $\vec{v}$, where $\vec{w} \parallel \vec{u}$:

Then $\vec{u}\times(\vec{v}+\vec{w})=\vec{u}\times\vec{v}+\vec{u}\times\vec{w}=\vec{u}\times\vec{v}+0=\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$.

Also, we can obtain the vector $\vec{v'}=(b, -a)$ from $\vec{v}=(a, b)$ as the following:

$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos(-90^{\circ}) & -\sin(-90^{\circ}) \\
\sin(-90^{\circ}) & \cos(-90^{\circ})
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
a \\
b
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
b \\
-a
\end{array}
\right]
$

Where the first matrix is a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).